# I have an E-Sata / USB combo port, does it mean I have USB 3.0?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, usb-3

I see a usb sign on the esata port so it's a combo, any usb device works on that but I am about to find usb 3.0 drivers because windows default driver doesn't see it as a sub 3.0 port. I tried forcing a driver and I had to reinstall windows again.
How can I know this port is USB 3.0?

Comment: USB3.0 ports have the Blue insert.

Comment: There's no such thing as an esata/usb combo port; they are entirely different.

Comment: @psusi: [Yes, there is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Esatap_port.JPG)

Comment: @Dennis, interesting... looks like the industry has gotten ahead of the standards bodies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your main question correctly. If you question is

> Is *every* E-Sata / USB combo port a USB 3.0 port?

the answer is **No**.

> How can I know this port is USB 3.0?

Refer to the manual / documentation of your motherboard, laptop or expansion card.